# I want the date view filter on current date, not on current time

Tags: views, datetime

I have schedule view in my project. I want to show the current day schedule in my view. We have following option in date filter.

"An offset from the current time such as "+1 day" or "-2 hours -30 minutes""

which gives you option for show the schedule from current time. which did not allow you to show the current day result. I used the "Views between dates filter" module but it gives filter on node created date only.

We can override the view by using the "hook_views_pre_build" hook.

Is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I have a view similar to what you're trying to achieve. You have to install the Date module (https://drupal.org/project/date) and through that module, you'll be able to set the granularity to 'Day' instead of minutes or seconds. Then, just put `+0 day` or `now`